# Refresh or update the button action

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

```
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh];
    NSLog(@"Value of txtfrequency in button fuinction :%@",txtfrequency.text);
    int z = [txtfrequency.text  intValue];
    NSLog(@"Value of z is :%d",z);
    int y = 10;
    //create a new dynamic button
    for (int j=0; j<z; j++)
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, y , 50, 30);
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button setTag:j];
        button.frame = frame;
        CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(100, y , 50, 30);

    textFieldRounded = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
    textFieldRounded.borderStyle =UIButtonTypeInfoDark;   //UITextBorderStyleNone;
    textFieldRounded.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //text color
    textFieldRounded.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];  //font size
    textFieldRounded.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; //background color
    textFieldRounded.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;   // no auto correction support

    textFieldRounded.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;  // type of the keyboard
    textFieldRounded.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  // type of the return key
    textFieldRounded.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; // has a clear 'x' button to the right
    textFieldRounded.delegate = self;
    [textFieldRounded setTag:j];

    //[[scroll viewWithTag:j] removeFromSuperview];
    [button reloadInputViews];
    [textFieldRounded removeFromSuperview];

    //[scroll 

    [scroll addSubview:button];
    scroll.contentSize= CGSizeMake(100, 1400);
    [scroll addSubview:textFieldRounded];
    y= y+50;


} 
}
```

Hii..

Above code generates no of buttons dynamically whenever user give input for buttons. But there is problem in this event.. e.g. User have given the input to generate 4 buttons ..then on view we get 4 buttons but now if user wantto have only 2 buttons then there is still 4 buttons on view. I am not able to refersh or update the action of button.

Anyone know how can I do this.

Please help me.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove all subviews from scrollview. just create a enumeration loop before adding buttons to scrollview like

```
 for(UIView *v in scroll){
     [v removeFromSuperView];
  }
```

put the above code before your loop.

Comment: Yes, before adding the buttons in the scroll view, remove all of them. Because, once you have added 4 buttons, i guess if you dont remove them, next time when you add 2 buttons they will appear on the first 2 buttons of the previously added 4 buttons, giving you an impression that still there are 4 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remember the current number of buttons. Let us say you store it in `numberOfButtons`.

You can clean up the existing text fields like this,

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh];
    int y = 10;

    for ( int i = 40; i < numberOfButtons+40; i++ ) {
        [[scroll viewWithTag:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    numberOfButtons = [txtfrequency.text intValue]; // Make `numberOfButtons` an ivar.

    for ( int i = 40; i < numberOfButtons+40; i++ ) {
        [..] // Add a button here.
    }
}
```

The problem with using fast enumeration is that you will be modifying the array which will raise an error.

Comment: This code cleanup the generated buttons but unable to regenerate the buttons on the same view.

Comment: Can you put this `if ( scroll == nil ) { NSLog(@"Nil Scrollview"); }` before the button creation code and tell me its result.

Comment: I didn't expect it to work. It did print "Nil Scrollview" on the console.

Comment: Yup, it making scroll view nill.

Comment: Ok start assigning tags from 40 or any higher number. Will update my answer.

Comment: The reason being that all views have a default tag of `0`. So when you ask `scroll` for `viewWithTag:0` then it returns itself. So it is necessary to avoid that `0`. There is no need for it to be `40` so you can pick any other number.